# Android firestore using "whereTo()" many times causes cost a lot?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a function to classify by user's region and MBTI.

Here is a code.

```
private void EventChangeListener() {
    //firestore.collection("Users").orderBy("time",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(50)
    firestore.collection("Users").orderBy("time",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(50)
            .whereEqualTo("gender","여자")
            .whereEqualTo("mbti","ENTP")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                    if(error != null){

                        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        Log.e("Firestore error",error.getMessage());
                        return;

                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()){

                        if (dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                            userArrayList.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(User.class));
                        }

                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

Like this whereEqualTo().whereEqualTo().whereEqualTo() causes a lot cost??

If It is right, then is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are charged for number of documents that match your query and are returned. Number of query clauses do not affect cost. Using more filters like `whereEqualTo().whereEqualTo().whereEqualTo()` will ideally reduce number of matches and cost less.

For example, if you have a collection of 50 restaurants and you use 1 `whereEqualTo` on 'city' field then it'll return and cost N only for restaurants that are present in that city. If you add another `whereEqualTo` on 'ratings' then number of matches might be even less than N.